# Como encontrar relacionamento e cardinalidade no MySQL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysql, cardinalidade, entidade-relacionamento

A imagem abaixo mostra um relacionamento entre duas tabelas criado a partir do MySQL Workbench.

O que estou precisando saber é como eu consigo encontrar essa informação dentro do banco de dados.

Eu preciso saber exatamente qual o tipo de cardinalidade (1:1 ou 1:n).

Já procurei dentro do "information_schema" e não consigo encontrar.

[image: Relacionamento entre 2 tabelas e cardinalidade]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cardinalidade (neste contexto) não é uma informação encontrada dentro do banco de dados. É um conceito que aplicamos na modelagem geral, para entendermos como é o relacionamento entre as tabelas.

Geralmente nos referimos nestes diagramas à cardinalidade esperada no relacionamento. Estes diagramas estão em um nível mais abstrato.

É até possível impor a cardinalidade através dos vários recursos do banco de dados como as *stored procedures*, *constraints* e *triggers*. Mas isto não dá uma informação inequívoca de qual é a cardinalidade, muito menos é algo obrigatório.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: bigown, realmente, tentei fazer uma reversão de um banco já existente em um novo projeto do Workbench e ele não identificou essa cardinalidade, eu pensei que isso era possível. Obrigado por sua ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode descobrir a cardinalidade no MySQL utilizando o comando `SHOW INDEX`.

Exemplo de uso:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM tabela FROM banco;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-index.html

Comment: Lembrando que, como @bigown disse, não é um valor exato. O MySQL apenas estima um valor, você pode tentar elaborar uma solução mais precisa com o uso do comando ANALYZE TABLE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: Na verdade esta cardinalidade é outra coisa. Isto não consegue informar a cardinalidade do relacionamento, que é o que a pergunta se refere. Informa apenas se os dados variam muito ou pouco. A maior cardinalidade significa que que todos os dados são diferentes e menor cardinalidade significa que todos os dados são iguais.

Comment: Eu já havia tentado usar o SHOW INDEX mas não consegui determinar o que preciso. @feresjorge como devo usar o ANALYZE TABLE para descobrir essa informação?

Comment: @bigown o que eu preciso realmente é saber se uma tabela tem um relacionamento com outra tipo uma LISTA ou uma ASSOCIAÇÃO. Não sei se existe outra técnica para descobrir isso, eu vi isso no Workbeach e achei que era guardado no banco.

Comment: Conforme a minha resposta não existe, pelo menos não no MySQL. Pode ser que exista alguma ferramenta que faça análise dos dados e tente descobrir, mas vai depender dos dados existentes. Enfim, não tem como.

Comment: Você pode tentar descobrir se o Workbench faz engenharia reversa assim como é possível através de um diagrama EER ter as querys de criação das tabelas.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Solução - MySQL Workbench]

Sei que é 2018, mas é uma dúvida que tive também e encontrei a solução. Gostaria de compartilhar com os demais.